# Basic Enter key functionality in C++Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, borland-c++

I am currently porting an old Borland C++Builder 5 project to C++Builder 10.3.

I have successfully ported all the project files, and it compiles and runs as intended, however there is an issue with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in some of the Forms.

The old project would always execute the same functionality as double clicking an item in the Form without the use of explicit code.

In the new project, this is not working. Pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on a selected object does nothing.

Is there some property in C++Builder 10.3 that needs to be set for this? Or, is it mandatory to write the explicit code in the Form's `OnKeyPress` event?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please provide an actual example of something that worked in 5 that is not working in 10.3. Key handling hasn't changed very much in the 20 years since 5's release.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for helping me out. So the forms that are not working are just derived classes of the TCustomListView component. They all have the FormKeyPress method overridden. In the old version, the enter key would just select the highlighted object in the list view. In 10.3, pressing enter on a highlighted object in the list view does nothing unless I implement the functionality myself in the FormKeyPress method. I was wondering if there was some property in the form that needs to be set so that pressing enter automatically selects the highlighted object in the listview ?

Comment: make sure your key event handlers are assigned to your components... It happened to me few times while porting to newer IDE that the headers and bodies of the events are there but the assignment was corrupt (`*.dfm`)... usual remedy is to clear the component event property (or set it to different handler) and then set it back to event handler routine it should use. However If you assign the handlers on runtime then its something else ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using C++Builder 10.4, I added a VCL ListView to a form with two items. I set up the ListView onKeyPress event handler. Then when I select one or the other items in the ListView and hit the enter key, I get the caption for the ListItem that was selected.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ListView1KeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
    if(ListView1->Selected)
    {
       Label1->Caption =
           ListView1->Items->Item[ListView1->Selected->Index]->Caption;
    }
}
```

Does this match code you have been using with older version of C++BUilder?